# how to post files with web request in asp.net 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, webrequest

i just want to post web request with multiple file from my server folder. Here I read this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566462/upload-files-with-httpwebrequest-multipart-form-data). I just want to use this technique with Microsoft.Net.Http package from NuGet.
here is my code :

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Collections;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Net.Http;
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Create web request object
        WebRequest objWebRequest;

        // Set url properties
        string url = "http://localhost:16047/EasyWeb/Admin/Post_History.aspx";
        objWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);
        objWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        // add sample form data
        ArrayList queryList = new ArrayList();
        queryList.Add(string.Format("{0}={1}", "title", HttpUtility.UrlDecode("From Admin to All Users 1")));
        queryList.Add(string.Format("{0}={1}", "desc", HttpUtility.UrlEncode("hi all users 1")));
        queryList.Add(string.Format("{0}={1}", "category", HttpUtility.UrlEncode("Test")));
        queryList.Add(string.Format("{0}={1}", "touser", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(string.Empty)));
        queryList.Add(string.Format("{0}={1}", "status", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(string.Empty)));
        queryList.Add(string.Format("{0}={1}", "group", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(string.Empty)));
        queryList.Add(string.Format("{0}={1}", "isfile", HttpUtility.UrlEncode("True")));
        queryList.Add(string.Format("{0}={1}", "sentdatetime", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(DateTime.Now.ToString())));
        var dir = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, "Files/"));
        int cnt = 0;
        foreach (FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles())
        {
            if (file.Exists)
            {
                cnt++;
               Upload(url, "file " + cnt.ToString(), file.Open(FileMode.Open), System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/PostedFile/" + file.Name)));
            }

        }
        // Set the encoding type
        objWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        string Parameters = String.Join("&", (String[])queryList.ToArray(typeof(string)));
        objWebRequest.ContentLength = Parameters.Length;
        //we get back the response after submission
        HttpWebResponse objHttpWebResponse;
        objHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)objWebRequest.GetResponse();
    }
    private System.IO.Stream Upload(string url, string param1, Stream fileStream, byte[] fileBytes)
    {
        HttpContent stringContent = new StringContent(param1);
        HttpContent fileStreamContent = new StreamContent(fileStream);
        HttpContent bytesContent = new ByteArrayContent(fileBytes);
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        using (var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
        {
            formData.Add(stringContent, "param1", "param1");
            formData.Add(fileStreamContent, "file1", "file1");
            formData.Add(bytesContent, "file2", "file2");
            var response = client.PostAsync(url, formData).Result;
            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return null;
            }
            return response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
        }
    }
}
```

this is the code of my receiver web app code :

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            using (DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext())
            {
                Session["Username"] = db.Users.Where(u => u.type_id.Equals("1")).Select(u => u.Username).FirstOrDefault();
                string title = null, desc = null, category = null, touser = null, status = null, group = null, isfile = null, sentdatetime = null;
                foreach (string strName in Request.Params)
                {
                    string strValue = Request.Form[strName];
                    switch (strName)
                    {
                        case "title":
                            title = strValue;
                            break;
                        case "desc":
                            desc = strValue;
                            break;
                        case "category":
                            category = strValue;
                            break;
                        case "touser":
                            touser = strValue;
                            break;
                        case "status":
                            status = strValue;
                            break;
                        case "group":
                            group = strValue;
                            break;
                        case "isfile":
                            isfile = strValue;
                            break;
                        case "sentdatetime":
                            sentdatetime = strValue;
                            break;
                    }
                }
                if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(title) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(desc) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(category) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(isfile))
                {
                    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
                    {
                        var query = Helper.GetProfile().ToList();
                        foreach (var item in query)
                        {
                            GV_ViewPost.PageSize = item.Page_Size;
                        }
                        Panel_AddNew.Visible = false;
                        Panel_View.Visible = false;
                        Session["CommandName"] = "Inbox";
                        Session["ColumnName"] = null;
                        Session["SearchtText"] = null;
                        this.FillGrid(Session["CommandName"].ToString(), (String)Session["ColumnName"] ?? null, (String)Session["SearchtText"] ?? null);
                        Bind_DDL_Column_List();
                        Bind_DDL_Category_List();
                        //Bind_Users_List();
                        Bind_DDL_Group();
                        Bind_DDL_Status();
                    }
                    this.GetData();
                }
                else
                {
                    int category_id = db.Categories.Where(c => c.Category_name.Equals(category)).Select(c => c.Id).FirstOrDefault();
                    int user_id = db.Users.Where(u => u.type_id.Equals("1")).Select(u => u.Id).FirstOrDefault();
                    System.Nullable<int> touser_id = null;
                    System.Nullable<int> status_id = null;
                    System.Nullable<int> group_id = null;
                    System.Nullable<DateTime> sent_datetime = null;
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(touser))
                    {
                        touser_id = db.Users.Where(u => (u.First_name + ' ' + u.Last_name).Equals(touser)).Select(u => u.Id).FirstOrDefault();
                    }
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(status))
                    {
                        status_id = db.Status.Where(s => s.status_name.Equals(status)).Select(s => s.Id).FirstOrDefault();
                    }
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(group))
                    {
                        group_id = db.Groups.Where(g => g.Group_name.Equals(group)).Select(g => g.Id).FirstOrDefault();
                    }
                    bool is_file = Convert.ToBoolean(isfile);
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sentdatetime))
                    {
                        sent_datetime = DateTime.Parse(sentdatetime);
                    }
                    Post myPost = new Post();
                    myPost.Title = title;
                    myPost.Category_id = category_id;
                    myPost.Description = desc;
                    myPost.User_id = user_id;
                    myPost.ToUser_id = touser_id;
                    myPost.status_id = status_id;
                    myPost.group_id = group_id;
                    myPost.IsFileAttached = is_file;
                    myPost.Sent_Datetime = sent_datetime;
                    db.Posts.InsertOnSubmit(myPost);
                    db.SubmitChanges();
                    int newId = myPost.Id;
                    if (is_file.Equals(true))
                    {
                        string val ;
                        double tot_file_size = 0;
                        for (int i = 0; i < Request.Params.AllKeys.AsQueryable(k=>k.); i++)
                        {
                            File myFile = new File();
                            HttpPostedFile uploadfile = fileCollection[i];
                            string fileTitle = Path.GetFileName(uploadfile.FileName);
                            string fileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss");
                            string fileType = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileTitle).ToString().ToLower();
                            myFile.Post_History_id = newId;
                            myFile.File_Title = fileTitle;
                            myFile.File_name = fileName;
                            myFile.File_ext = fileType;
                            double file_size = int.Parse(uploadfile.ContentLength.ToString()) / 1024;
                            tot_file_size += file_size;
                            myFile.File_Size = file_size;
                            if (uploadfile.ContentLength > 0)
                            {
                                uploadfile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/PostFiles/") + fileName + fileType);
                                db.Files.InsertOnSubmit(myFile);
                                db.SubmitChanges();
                            }
                        }
                        db.UpdatePostField(newId, "TotalFileSize", tot_file_size.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
            ImageButton7.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "src='../images/export_over.gif'");
            ImageButton7.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "src='../images/export.gif'");
            ImageButton8.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "src='../images/print_over.gif'");
            ImageButton8.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "src='../images/print.gif'");
            ImageButton9.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "src='../images/grouptree_over.gif'");
            ImageButton9.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "src='../images/grouptreed.gif'");
            btnFirst.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "src='../images/first_over.gif'");
            btnFirst.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "src='../images/First.gif'");
            btnPrev.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "src='../images/prev_over.gif'");
            btnPrev.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "src='../images/Prev.gif'");
            btnNext.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "src='../images/next_over.gif'");
            btnNext.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "src='../images/next.gif'");
            btnLast.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "src='../images/last_over.gif'");
            btnLast.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "src='../images/last.gif'");
            ImageButton14.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "src='../images/gotopage_over.gif'");
            ImageButton14.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "src='../images/gotopage.gif'");
            ImageButton16.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "src='../images/search_over.gif'");
            ImageButton16.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "src='../images/Search.gif'");
    }
```

by trying to run this code i found error like :

```
You must provide a request body if you set ContentLength>0 or SendChunked==true.  Do this by calling [Begin]GetRequestStream before [Begin]GetResponse.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Net.ProtocolViolationException: You must provide a request body if you set ContentLength>0 or SendChunked==true.  Do this by calling [Begin]GetRequestStream before [Begin]GetResponse.

Source Error: 


Line 55:         //we get back the response after submission
Line 56:         HttpWebResponse objHttpWebResponse;
Line 57:         objHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)objWebRequest.GetResponse();
Line 58:     }
Line 59:     private System.IO.Stream Upload(string url, string param1, Stream fileStream, byte[] fileBytes)

Source File: c:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\WebSites\WebRequest\Default.aspx.cs    Line: 57 

Stack Trace: 


[ProtocolViolationException: You must provide a request body if you set ContentLength>0 or SendChunked==true.  Do this by calling [Begin]GetRequestStream before [Begin]GetResponse.]
   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +6038249
   _Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\WebSites\WebRequest\Default.aspx.cs:57
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +91
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +74
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2207

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1
```

Comment: Did you try this code? Does it work? If so, I guess it is okay. If not, what is the issue with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your attempt to get all files:

```
foreach (FileInfo file in Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, "Files/"))
```

You should use something like this:

```
foreach (string filename in Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, "Files/")))
{
    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filename);

    ...
}
```

Comment: okay here i pass Stream.Null is it right or something else that i have to pass it.

Comment: I would remove the entire stream part and read the bytes yourself like in the second line or use File.Open to create the FileStream.

Comment: can u set up my receiver web app code from retrieving files that i posted from this code.

Comment: That question is way to broad to answer in just one go. If you want to, create a new question and make clear what your requirements are.

Comment: i modify my Upload line to this way Upload(url, "file " + cnt.ToString(), file.Open(FileMode.Open), System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/PostedFile/" + file.Name)));

Answer (score 0):

```
var dir= new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, "Files/"));

foreach (FileInfo file in dir.GetFiles())
{
    if (file.Exists)
    {
         // upload 
    }

}
```